# Test both pages using split gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the [split](https://github.com/splitrb/split) gem for A/B testing. I have 2 versions of a page for the test. How can our tester test both of these pages without changing the code?

I tested it simply by changing `show` to `show_b` in

```
- if @experiment == 'b'
      = render "show_b"
    - else
      = render "show"
```

But how can the tester do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a tester to be able to force a certain alternative to render a particular template, you can pass a URL parameter to override the normal behavior.

In your controller, you should have something like this to assign the test:

```
@experiment = ab_test("experiment_name", "a", "b")
```

For a tester to access a specific version (and not have the test alternative randomly assigned), you can format the URL like so:

```
http://myawesomesite.com?experiment_name=b
```

This will always assign the `b` test alternative, and render the `show_b` template.

See [this section of the Split documentation](https://github.com/splitrb/split#overriding-alternatives) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Where you assign @experiment variable? If it from DB you can simple change it via admin panel, before visit page.